# CORS Policy blocking request even with Access Allow Origin set to *

Tags: angular, typescript, express, cors

I am getting the following error in my console when trying to have a POST called on my site. (Angular front end with Express back end all inside a Docker container).

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://exp.mysite.com/i_l' from origin 'https//frontend.mysite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Note I have this setup exactly the same on my local PC and everything works fine.

Below is how my server.js file on the express side is configured for CORS:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const DIR = './uploads';

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, DIR);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

let upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

  next();
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Node.js server is running on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A better appraoch of enabling CORS on your express server is by using **[`cors`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)**

Try this. First:

```
npm install cors --save
```

Then:

```
...
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();
...

app.use(cors());

...
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out -- I received the same error using this method as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, the wild card * is invalid. You need to return the specific ORIGIN:

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https//frontend.mysite.com");
```

Comment: Switched to this instead of the * and received the following: CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing. Even though I clearly have:

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://frontend.mysite.com');

Comment: The protocol and port are important. Have you seen the headers in the browser? That are correct?